# В чём разница между комментарием и ответом?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, ответы

Не могу понять, почему на стековерфлоу многие на заданный вопрос пишут комментарии, которые вполне полностью отвечают на вопрос. Но не оформляют это в качестве ответа.

Есть какой-то лимит на количество ответов?) Или почему бы сразу не добавить свой текст как ответ?

P.S. я не так давно пользуюсь сервисом и видимо ещё многое не понял тут, но вот эта ситуация встречается довольно часто.

Comment: когда лень писать полноценный ответ, или не хочется сильно погружаться, или когда ответ уже есть в другом вопросе, тогда отвечают намеком/ссылкой. Ответ предназначен для полного ответа на вопрос, а это занимает больше времени чем коммент.